# Ngx Spinner blocks devtools

Tags: angular, electron, desktop-application, ngx-spinner

I'm using **Angular 11** and **ngx-spinner** as:

```
<ngx-spinner [fullScreen]="false" bdColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.015)"
         type="ball-clip-rotate" size="medium" 
         color="#23313F"></ngx-spinner>
```

My problem is that, whenever the spinner is active, I can not open devtools (it seems like the spinner somehow blocks all keyboard events).

- Keyboard events works outside the browser or at another tab (blocking app view space).
- Sometimes it blocks also pointer-events (it's kind of weird it happens sometimes only).

As the code shows, it's set to **fullscreen: false**, otherwise blocking pointer events would be a espected behaviour, but as it's set to false, it should be blocking only it's containers' div.

I'm using **ngx-spinner: 11.0.1** (but I had the same issue with previous versions too).

**Update**

After testing with different apps, and the same libraries, the problem is only happening at my **Electron-Angular App**. When using same libraries but with web app (using chrome) devtools open normally.

Comment: i think you set the fullscreen: false to use spinner in specific <div> but i think you miss one point.that <div> should contain "position: relative" style to apply only on that.